# How do I make the unicode-range in @font-face for only load Latin characters? (css)

Tags: html, css, unicode, font-face, unicode-string

I'm using **only** the Latin range characters for website, but in my woff2/ttf there are many other types of characters like **Š Č â**... How do I sets the specific range for **only Latin characters** using `unicode-range` - `@font-face` ?

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is in having all the characters?

Comment: I see normal woff2/ttf files have only latin characters and it's much lighter than files with lots of characters. I think unicode range will offload...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the aim is to lighten the download of a complete font then unicode-range will not help.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

> The unicode-range CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters to be used from a font defined by @font-face and made available for use on the current page. If the page doesn't use any character in this range, the font is not downloaded; if it uses at least one, the whole font is downloaded.

The only way forward would seem to be to create another font using only the required characters.